# Symfony createQueryBuilder array_diff

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I need compare two array and if compare true set result in another array. I have entity Developer who have field $skills = array(); and I have some logic for find developer who have skills in arrayskills. I need compare 100%. If developer have 10 skills and I compare for 4 skills and all 4 skills to be in skills developer - set this developer in $arrayResults. Help please

```
    public function findBySkills($skills)
 {
    $date = new \DateTime;

    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');

    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer', 'd')

        ->getQuery();

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();

    $arrayResults = array();

    foreach ($results as $result) {


        if(!$result->getSkills()) {
            $arrayResults[] = $result;
        } else {
            if (is_array($result->getSkills())) {

                $find = array_diff($result->getSkills(), $skills);

            }
        }
    }


    return $arrayResults;
}
```

Comment: Don't see what this really has to do with Symfony.  Sounds like what you want is array_intersect.

Comment: I use symfony and this function in developer repository

Comment: Sorry, my comment was not complete.  With array_intersect you get an array where the items intersect.  If return from array_intersect == $skills then it's a match, based on what you're saying.

Comment: array_intersect ($result->getSkills(), $skills) ? 
and if (array_intersect == $skills)
$arrayResults[] = $result;
??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure but you can do it a bit more compactly:

```
if (count($skills) === count(array_intersect($result->getSkills(), $skills))) {
    $arrayResults[] = $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my problem

```
 public function findBySkills($skills)
{
    $count_skills = count($skills);

    $qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder('d');

    $qb
        ->select('d')
        ->from('ArtelProfileBundle:Developer', 'd')

        ->getQuery();

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $results = $query->getResult();

    $arrayResults = array();

    foreach ($results as $result) {


        if(!$result->getSkills()) {
            $arrayResults[] = $result;
        } else {
            if (is_array($result->getSkills())) {

                $find = array_intersect($result->getSkills(), $skills);
                if(count($find) == $count_skills){
                    $arrayResults[] = $result;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    return $arrayResults;
}
```